# calling view methods from a view controller

Tags: iphone

This is a simple question, and I'm sure I got it work in the past. I'm trying to call a method in a view

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface View : UIView {
}

-(void)spinAction;

@end
```

from a view controller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "View.h"

@interface layers3ViewController : UIViewController {   
    IBOutlet View *view;
}

-(IBAction)spinButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

via the  method

```
-(IBAction)spinButton:(id)sender{
    [view spinAction];
}
```

but cannot get to it work. Everything is put together using the Interface Builder. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? A previous code worked by putting

```
[self.view spinAction]
```

albeit with error messages but not even that works here. Any hints / suggestions more than welcome.

Comment: Is your ivar actually named "view"?

Comment: I think so, but maybe this is a bad choice of name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.view` returns an object of class UIView, and you probably shouldn't try to change that. You need to create a new outlet with a class of `View`, and wire it up in interface builder.

```
@interface layers3ViewController : UIViewController {   
    IBOutlet MyView *myView;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MyView *myView;


-(IBAction)spinButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

In your implementation should look like this:

```
@implementation layers3ViewController
@synthesize myView;
-(IBAction)spinButton:(id)sender{
    [self.myView spinAction];
}
```

Don't forget to connect the myView outlet in Interface Builder to your view.

Comment: That seemed to work and even without the @property and @synthesize directives. I now have a View and a MyView which is fine. Many thanks for this and everyone else for their feedback. Onwards to the next problem ...

Answer (score 2):

`view` is already a property of UIViewController and it is an `IBOutlet` so I'm not sure wich `view` would be set when you make the association in interface builder.
Try this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "View.h"

@interface layers3ViewController : UIViewController {   
    //IBOutlet View *view;
}

-(IBAction)spinButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

and

```
-(IBAction)spinButton:(id)sender
{
    View *myView = (View *)self.view;
    [myView spinAction];
}
```

and of course in Interface Builder make sure the object your associating to the `view` outlet is an instance of your `View` class.

Comment: Many thanks for this; could not quite get it to work. I suspect the problem is due to the choice of the variable name view. Many thanks though; it certainly makes things feel clearer.